# Set json property name based on Class

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson

I have code similar to this:

```
public interface Animal {}

public class Dog implements Animal {
    String tag = "ABC";
}

public class Eagel implements Animal {
    int speed = 125;
}

public class World{
    Animal animal;
}
```

A dog should then resulting in something like this:

```
{
    "animal" : {
        "tag" : "ABC"
    }
}
```

**Question**: How can I rename the property "animal" to "dog" when the animal is a dog and "eagel" when it is an eagel?

**Trials:**
My best guess is to set this in the interface class like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
              include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
              property = "animal")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog")
    @Type(value = Eagel.class, name = "eagel")
public interface Animal {}
```

But cant get it to work. Also tried to use @JsonRootName for Dog and Eagel without any result. Am I supposed to use @JsonSubTypes for this to work? Have only manage to add properties with the @JsonSubTypes and not change an existing one. Using jackson 2.7. My json mapper is also set to:

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```

**Edit:** Minimum complete example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonNaming {

    interface Animal {}

    class Dog implements Animal {
        private String tag = "ABC";

        public Dog() {}

        public String getTag() {
            return tag;
        }

        public void setTag(String tag) {
            this.tag = tag;
        }
    }

    class World {
        @JsonSubTypes(@Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"))
        private Animal animal;

        public World() {}

        public Animal getAnimal() {
            return animal;
        }

        public void setAnimal(Animal animal) {
            this.animal = animal;
        }
    }

    public JsonNaming() {
        World world = new World();
        world.setAnimal(new Dog());
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(world);
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JsonNaming();
    }
}
```

Result: *{"animal":{"tag":"ABC"}}*

Goal: *{"dog":{"tag":"ABC"}}*

Comment: Spelling nazi here: it's Eagle, not Eagel :-)

Comment: use @JsonProperty("key_name") annotation for the fields you want to set the property name

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [JsonObjectBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObjectBuilder.html)?

Comment: At a first glance "JsonObjectBuilder" do not generate the correct property name? I need to be able to generate this from Classes containing hundreds of properties.